# Why does expect spawn change from iso8859-1 to UTF8?

Tags: expect, spawn

The problem is when you run the program spawn a command whose arguments lead accented vowels code page `iso8859-1`, I think it translates to spawn `utf8` so that the command does not work well.

Anyone know the reason for this translation. Am I doing something wrong?

Greetings and many thanks in advance.
Sorry for my English.

Example:

```
expect1.1> exp_version    
5.32.1

expect1.2>  puts "[ encoding system ]"    
iso8859-1

expect1.3> exp_spawn ssh david@localhost  'grep **CASTELLÓN** provincia'    
exp_spawn ssh david@localhost 'grep **CASTELLÃN** provincia'
3656

expect1.4>
```

In this example we can see how the word becomes `CASTELLÓN  ->  CASTELLÃN`.